# How to delete certain lists from a nested list?

Tags: list-manipulation, pattern-matching, filtering

I have a nested list as the following example (want to remove lists with same or incremented elements such as `{1,2,3,4,5}, {2,2,2,2,2}, {1,1,1,1,1}`):

```
test={{1,2,3,4,5}, {1,1,1,1,1}, {2,4,6,8,10}, {2,2,2,2,2}, {3,5,2,4,8}};
test1=DeleteCases[test,{1,2,3,4,5}];
test1=DeleteCases[test1,{1,1,1,1,1}];
test1=DeleteCases[test1,{2,2,2,2,2}];
```

So the result is `test1={{3,5,2,4,8}}`(here I also delete the case {2,4,6,8,10} due to the equal increaments).

With the above way I can get the list which removes the list that elements are the same or incremented.

The problem is ***when the `test` is very large and I don't know what exactly elements are***, how can I efficiently remove the lists where elements are the same or incremented? Is there a clever way to do this?

Thanks for all the help in advance!

Comment: Is `{-1,-2,-3,-4,-5}` also to be removed? It has constant increment `-1`.

Comment: yes, arbitrary constant increment. @kglr and @JJBK has already given some answers. These answers can be modified such as `Select[test, (! Equal @@ #) && (! Equal @@ Differences[#]) &]` or `DeleteCases[_?(MatchQ[{((n_) ..)}]@*Differences)]@test`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
Select[Not @* Apply[Equal] @* Differences ] @ test

Pick[test, Developer`ToPackedArray[Unitize@Total[Abs @ Differences[#, 2]]& /@ test], 1]

Select[Not @* MatchQ[{(a_) ..}] @* Differences] @ test

Cases[_?(Not @* MatchQ[{(a_) ..}] @* Differences)] @ test

DeleteCases[_?(MatchQ[{(a_) ..}] @* Differences)] @ test
```

all give

> {{3, 5, 2, 4, 8}}

**Update:** Adding a pattern *"to remove the cases like {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1,3}, where elements repeated in even and odd positions"*

```
test2 = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 4, 6, 8, 10}, {2, 2, 2, 2, 2}, 
  {3, 5, 2, 4, 8}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3} };

Select[Not @* MatchQ[{(a_) ..| 
   PatternSequence[(PatternSequence[a_, b_]/; a==-b)..,a_]}] @* Differences] @ 
 test2
```

> {{3, 5, 2, 4, 8}}

Alternatively,

```
Fold[Select[Not @* #2] @ # &, 
 test2,
 {Apply[Equal] @* Differences,  MatchQ[{PatternSequence[a_, b_  ]..}]}]
```

> {{3, 5, 2, 4, 8}}

Comment: wow, amazing! thank you so much

Comment: Do you also how to apply to remove the cases like {1, 0, 1, 0, 1,0,1,0,1,0}, {1, 3, 1, 3, 1,3,1,3,1,3}, where elements repeated in even and odd positions? thank you very much!

Comment: @XuemeiGu Use https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRepeat.html as `Select[test, Length@FindRepeat@# > 2 &]` to remove all lists that are just 2 repeated elements.

Comment: @XuemeiGu, please see the update.

Comment: @lirtosiast, this is a very nice solution. I just find out that `FindRepeat` is new in mathematica 11.2. I didn't realize this function because of my old version. Thanks!

Comment: @kglr, that works! thank you so much for the update.

Answer (score 5):

```
Select[test, (! Equal @@ #) && (! AllTrue[Differences[#], EqualTo[1]]) &]
```

Comment: thank you very much! Your method is very quick compare to my for-loop way, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You say you're interested in working with large lists. In that case it is better to avoid [`Select`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Select). Here is an alternate function using [`Dot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dot) and [`Pick`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Pick):

```
removeProgressions[list_?MatrixQ]:=Module[{len=Dimensions[list][[2]]},
    Pick[list, Unitize @ Total[Abs[list . Partition[{1,-2,1}, len-2, 1, {-1, 1}, 0]], {2}], 1]
]
```

Timing comparison:

```
SeedRandom[1]
list = RandomInteger[10, {10^6, 5}];
r1 = removeProgressions[list]; //AbsoluteTiming
r2 = Select[Not @* MatchQ[{(a_)..}] @* Differences] @ list; //AbsoluteTiming

r1===r2
```

> {0.138829, Null}
>
> {1.98615, Null}
>
> True

Comment: Ah, the discrete Laplacian in disguise! Very neat.

Answer (score 2):

I think the OP wanted to remove sub-lists that used any constant increment, be it 0, 1, or some larger integer. The expression

```
Select[test, Length@Intersection@Differences[#] > 1 &]
```

removes all sub-lists with a constant increment (including in the example, those with increments of 0, 1, and 2).

Answer (score 1):

```
test = {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}, {1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, {2, 4, 6, 8, 10}, {2, 2, 2, 
    2, 2}, {3, 5, 2, 4, 8}, {-1, -2, -3, -4, -5}};

Select[test, !AllTrue[# == 0 &][Differences@Differences@#] &]
```

> {{3, 5, 2, 4, 8}}

Answer (score 1):

Using `GroupBy` and `Lookup`:

```
Lookup[GroupBy[test, Length@Intersection@Differences[#] > 1 &], True]

(*{{3, 5, 2, 4, 8}}*)
```